Do compound eyes exist in nature that have multiple "pixels" per ommatidium?
If yes, which species? What is the terminology for such eyes?

Have you performed some research yourself? What brought a Google search?

Uhm, I just got curious about it when thinking about fake pupils of crabs.

I thinkt it's a good question, yet we require folks to show some evidence of previous research efforts; a simple wikipedia search can do the job. Adding your own preliminary findings is a great way to bring focus and clarity to your post. You can also see that the answerer below had difficulty to answer your question because of a lack of information in the question

This question is the subject of this meta post.

OK, I've researched a bit and found this:


In apposition compound eyes each lens with its associated photoreceptors is an independent unit (the ommatidium), which views the light from a small region of the outside world.
In superposition eyes the optical elements do not act independently; instead, they act together to produce a single erect image lying deep in the eye. In this respect they have more in common with single-chambered eyes, even though the way the image is produced is quite different.

Source: https://www.britannica.com/science/photoreception/Compound-eyes
So superposition eyes are not exactly multiple "pixels" (rhabdoms) packed into a single ommatidium, but rather each rhabdom served by multiple ommatidia! In this regard, superposition compound eyes work similar to microlens array cameras sans the main lens! 


This details two general classes of compound eyes, but doesn't answer the question. Perhaps the original question should have been edited with this information, rather than posting it as an answer.

@JiminyCricket. Karl Popper says it is scientifically impossible to prove that something does not exist, because it could exist where you weren't looking.
Also, why doesn't this answer answer the question? The question was about multiple "pixels" per ommatidia, and every ommatidium in superposition eyes does illuminate multiple pixels.

My comment wasn't philosophical in nature, just pragmatic. It's just the sort of background research that would have been great in the question's body. Perhaps you are unaware that there is a definitive answer to the question, and that this isn't it.

@JiminyCricket. How can any person definitevly know that no species in the world has compound eyes with multiple species per isolated ommatidium? All you can say is that you haven't learned about any such species so far, which is not a definitive answer.

@JiminyCricket. Also, you didnt explain why you believe that superposition eyes do not match the original phrasing of my question (still in the question's title).

You're making an incorrect assumption about the answer to the question in your comment that you can't prove a negative - why would anyone need to do that when they can cite a positive? Regarding your answer; omatidium is the singular of omatidia, you've answered a different question - or rather you've shown background research to the original question which should be edited to include it, rather than posting it as an answer.
